# Is $\nabla = -\text{div}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here there's is the following equation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_homogenization

$$\nabla \cdot \bigg( A \bigg( \frac{\vec{x}}{\epsilon} \bigg) \nabla u_{\epsilon} \bigg) = f$$

where $\nabla$ is used, but here:
http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~lototsky/Math625-14/H-notes.pdf

the equation reads:

$$- \text{div} \cdot \bigg( A \bigg( \frac{\vec{x}}{\epsilon} \bigg) \nabla u_{\epsilon} \bigg) = f$$

So is $\nabla = - \text{div}$?

Comment: $\nabla\cdot$ is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $\nabla$ (read "nabla") is defined by
$$\nabla = \begin{pmatrix} \partial_{x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \partial_{x_n} \end{pmatrix} $$
so $\nabla u$ is just the gradient of $u$ (for a scalar field $u$). But taking the dot product $\nabla \cdot u$ (for a vectorial $u$) gives
$$\nabla \cdot u =  \begin{pmatrix} \partial_{x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \partial_{x_n} \end{pmatrix}  \cdot \begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_n \end{pmatrix} = \partial_{x_1} u_1 + \cdots + \partial_{x_n} u_n = \mathrm{div}\,u.$$
So in some sense $\nabla \cdot = \mathrm{div}$, but $\nabla \neq \mathrm{div}$.

The minus sign here is not important, just replace $f$ by $-f$ to see that the two equations are actually the same.

Comment: Could you clarify the "in some sense" part? Why is it not exactly equal?

Comment: Why can I replace $-f$ by $f$?

Comment: In some sense because the computations are formal !

Comment: Well if you define $g=-f$, you get the same equation with a different source term $g$ instead of $f$. I just want to point out that it does not really change the nature of the equation.

Comment: But then one's solving for the opposite sign? I.e. one gets a solution of the opposite sign as well?

Comment: Yes you can check

Answer (score 0):

"$\nabla \cdot F$" is a common way of writing the divergence of the vector field $F$, in accordance with the Cartesian formula noted by @Héhéhé's answer. This is not brilliant notation, because while it tells you the result should be a scalar, it doesn't tell you that the formula in other coordinate systems is more complicated than a bog-standard Euclidean scalar product (since the coordinate system itself then changes from point-to-point, and so also has to be differentiated). But "$\nabla \cdot F$" does universally mean the scalar that reduces to $\sum_i \partial F_i / \partial x_i $ in Cartesian coordinates.

---

On the other hand, $\operatorname{div}{F}$ is the (strictly more correct) notation for the divergence, but has two conventions associated to it: it may mean "the scalar that reduces to $\sum_i \partial F_i / \partial x_i $ in Cartesian coordinates", or it may mean "the scalar that reduces to $-\sum_i \partial F_i / \partial x_i $ in Cartesian coordinates". Why are both used? The former has the signs on the derivatives positive, which is what we expect in general for differential operators. But if you think of the divergence as a sort of formal adjoint of the gradient, then because by Green's (first?) identity
$$ \int_V (\nabla\phi) \cdot F = -\int_V \phi \nabla \cdot F + \text{boundary terms}, $$
it makes sense to take the negative sign so that $\langle \nabla \phi , F \rangle = \langle \phi, \operatorname{div}{F} \rangle$.

We see the same thing in the conventions for the Laplacian: $\Delta f$ means $\operatorname{div}\operatorname{grad} f$, with one of the conventions for $\operatorname{div}$. Another good reason is then that this definition makes the Laplacian a nonnegative operator since $$ \int_V f \nabla \cdot (\nabla f) = -\int_V \lvert \nabla f \rvert^2 + \text{boundary terms}. $$ Really, a text should say somewhere which convention is used.