# Notation: $\nabla \cdot$, div, $\nabla$, grad, ...?

Tags: notation, vector-analysis, tensors

I am currently finding myself doing lots of applied mathematics, e.g. fluid dynamics, and of course this involves a lot of vector calculus amongst other things. This had me thinking about proper notation. Prompted by Chappers answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203724/is-nabla-textdiv) question (I could not find additional posts on this website discussing this particular irregularity), I decided to probe you guys a bit further. Disregarding common conventions in the applied fields, I would like to hear your perspectives. Knowing that people have different preferences when it comes to notation, I was wondering if you have any (as there often are) good arguments for using one notation over the other:

Let $f$ be a scalar field and $\mathbf{F}$ a vector field.

Do you write $\text{grad} f$ or $\nabla f$? $\text{div } \mathbf{F}$ or $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$? $\text{curl } \mathbf{F}$ or $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}$? Etc. And why?

How about when generalizing to tensor fields?

I'm looking forward to hearing your responses.

Comment: I see the textual notations more as describing a *concept* while the notations with nabla ($\nabla$) are formulas for how to compute them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I, for myself, prefer the spelled-out variants, at least when doing analysis:
$$\mathop{\mathrm{grad}} f, \quad \mathop{\mathrm{div}} \mathbf F, \quad \mathop{\mathrm{rot}} \mathbf F  $$
The variant $\nabla f$ for the gradient is ok, but I like consistency, and using the same "style" underlines the connection between the three operations (more below). Sometimes, however, especially when doing physics, I need to revert to the "physicist $\nabla$ notation" because some formulae look a lot more familiar that way, e.g.
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf E = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} $$
For the laplacian, instead, I very much favor the notation $\Delta f$, since I find it easy to confuse $\nabla^2 f$ with $\nabla f$ or the bilaplacian $\Delta^2 f$ at first glance. Plus the big triangle is something specific to the laplacian, which makes it recognizable to me – it screams "heat equation". Same for the dalembertian $\square_c f$ (which I write in the mathematician's way, without the $^2$).
$$\Delta u = \beta \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}, \qquad \square_c u = \frac 1 {c^2} \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} - \Delta u = 0 $$
It all changes when I need to do tensors on manifolds. All the first-order derivative operators are instances of the exterior derivative on forms (of different degree), so it is best to keep it simple:
$$F = F_{\mu\nu} \mathop{}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\wedge \mathop{}\mathrm{d} x^\nu = B + E \wedge \mathop{}\mathrm d x^0, \qquad \mathrm d F = 0 $$
If you want to be acting on vector fields or scalar fields on three-dimensional manifolds specifically, though, you may "redefine" the differential operations with the Hodge star, the external derivative, and the musical isomorphisms:
$$\mathop{\mathrm{grad}} f = (\mathrm d f)^\sharp, \quad \mathop{\mathrm{div}} X = \star \mathrm d{\star}(X^\flat), \quad \mathop{\mathrm{rot}} X= \left(\star \mathrm d (X^\flat) \right)^\sharp$$
Heck, you may even redefine the laplacian as $\mathop{\mathrm{grad}}(\mathop{\mathrm{div}})$:
$$\Delta f = \star \mathrm d {\star} \mathrm d f$$
Also, in the context of differential geometry I prefer to denote the standard real-analytic partial derivatives as $\partial_k$, leaving the $\partial / \partial x^k$ to be abstract vectors on a manifold with respect to a chart $x$.

---

**Bonus.** Here is a diagrammatic depiction of the action of the first order differential operators on $p$-forms over a $3$-dimensional manifold $M$:
[image]
Here $\Omega^p$ denotes the space of $p$-forms $\Omega^p(M)$, while $\Gamma = \Gamma(TM)$ is the space of smooth sections of the tangent bundle, i.e. vector fields. $0$ is just the space $\Omega^4= \Omega^5 = \dots$, which is the trivial vector space.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed input! Definitely something to think about. Love the musical isomorphisms haha. And great bonus! Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to giobrach, I prefer the nabla because it clearly indicates that $\nabla f$, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$, $\nabla \times \mathbf{F}$ and $\nabla^2 f$ are vector, scalar, vector and scalar respectively. I never use $\Delta$ for Laplacian.

Also, from a dimensional analysis point of view each occurrence of $\nabla$ carries with it dimensions of reciprocal length. This information is hidden if spelt operators are used. When Cartesian coordinates are specified (and no curls are being taken) I find myself writing $\partial/\partial\mathbf{x}$ in place of $\nabla$, which makes the dimensionality even clearer, and e.g. with scaling $\hat{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{x}/L$ we have

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
 = \frac{1}{L} \frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{\mathbf{x}}}, \qquad
   \frac{\partial}{\partial\hat{\mathbf{x}}}
 = L \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}.
$$